# How can I get the Class name from a swing Component?

Tags: java, swing, class, netbeans

How can I print the class name from the component?

Comment: 1) See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Question changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how can I print the class name from the component

```
component.getClass().getName();
```

Comment: Hmm, I looked in [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) and there is no getClass() method there. Where should I look for this sort of info?

Comment: @bob, keep going. You will also see a section on: `Methods inherited from class java.lang.Object`.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it must be there somewhere!